# How to avoid getting killed by a tank?

Tags: battlefield-1

Assuming I'm not playing as **Assault** and the most *harmfull* thing I can do is throw a grenade or hit it with **K-Bullets** (not a good option as I'd be seen), how do I survive to a tank?

*Side note: hiding inside a building is not an option*